# С помощью чего реализуется авторизация?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

В реальных проектах на asp.mvc для аутентификации-авторизации пользуются дефолтными провайдерами членства и ролей, или наследуются и пользуются своими? Или вообще проверяют данные пользователя непосредственно в контроллере без использования Membership.ValidateUser?

И заодно используют ли formsAuthentication, или что-то другое?

Comment: В реальных проектах может использоваться всё что угодно: ваш вопрос сформулирован так, что дать объективный ответ на него непросто.

Comment: посмотрите на [tag:asp.net-identity-2] который используется в шаблоне [tag:asp.net-mvc] приложения

Comment: все зависит от того насколько Вас устраивает *стандартное* решение

Comment: Провайдеры членства и ролей решают задачу аутентификации, а не авторизации.

Comment: немного тут https://habrahabr.ru/company/dataart/blog/311376/
можно прочитать

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться.